# Set zoom for web view in android

Tags: android, webkit, android-webview

I want to set zoom for showing content on web view in android. How is it possible to zoom the web view for specific level. Please give me a solution.

Comment: Next time, show what you have tried. And try to be a little nicer :) "Could you send me in the good direction" or something like that instead of "Give me solution".

Answer (score 1):

Try using the webView Settings

use the webSettings class

```
webview.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
```

Check out Set zoom for Webview